# Running Code First migrations from 1 project in another

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a bit of an unusual problem that I will try to explain as best I can.

I have 1 WebAPI project, which makes use of Entity Framework migrations.  This is all working perfectly well with the below setup. The webapi project has a reference to my Repositories project, which houses `MyContext`, all my migration files and all the migration configuration

Global.asax.cs in WebAPI project

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Repositories.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

Configuration.cs in Repositories project

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    public Configuration(DbConnectionInfo _info)
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        TargetDatabase = _info;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyContext _context)
    {
        MyContextSeeder.Seed(_context, logger);
        base.Seed(_context);
    }
}
```

I also have a method which can create a new database with a new context depending on the connection string passed in.  This works perfectly well from within my WebAPI project, and can call it on the fly to create databases and migrate them to latest.

```
public static MyContext UpdateDatabase(string _connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = new MContext(_connectionString);
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
            DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration(new DbConnectionInfo(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient")));
            migrator.Update();
            return context;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            logger.Error("Error updating database", err);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The task I am now trying to achieve is to run these migrations from another, totally separate application.
So far I have managed to get the migrations running, and the database is being created and migrations run (but it should be noted that the seed does not appear to be getting called), but it is reporting an error of:

```
Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
```

Within this separate application, which is a windows form app, all I have essentially done is include references to my repositories project (and other related projects required e.g. Models) and called the `UpdateDatabase` method detailed above.

So the code in the forms app can be watered down to:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    MyContext.UpdateDatabase(newConnectionString);
}
```

Has anyone had any experience in developing something similar before, or am I going about this the wrong way?  It seems simple enough what I am trying to achieve, but just not quite there.